# How to read spring bean xml configuration file and convert to java pojo object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb, spring-bean

Need to convert the spring bean xml file to java pojo object.
is there any library which parses spring bean file ?

spring bean xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans 
               xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
                   
            
             <import resource= "resource1" />
             
             <import resource= "resource2" />
             
             <context:annotation-config />
                         
             <context:component-scan base-package="org.example1, org.example2"/>
              
        </beans>
```

Comment: put that xml file in classpath!
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("xxx.xml");. then use context.getBean("beanname", classname.class); to get that bean;

Comment: i need to read all the properties that are present in the xmls for ex : base-packages in component-scan, resource in import. not only beans.